# Performance issue when setting TTL for Ignite cache

Tags: java, ignite

I observed that when a TTL is set for the cache, the get operation drastically slows down: it is 4 - 5x slower comparing with the case when no TTL is set.
The only setting which I used is:

```
return new CacheConfiguration<String, Object>("MyCache")
                .setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED)
                .setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC)
                .setDataRegionName("MyDataRegion")
                .setExpiryPolicyFactory(AccessedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(cacheTtlDuration)); // cacheTtlDuration is by default 120 minutes
```

Should I set some additional configuration parameters, or is this a known issue? I expect to see a difference, still this huge difference is a bit strange too me...

Note: I attached a screenshot containing a comparison between the 2 cases. I took the call stack with JProfiler (instrumentation mode, instrumenting only the org.apache.ignite packages)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyfD1.jpg)

Comment: Duration of 120 what? This isn't expected behaviour, and I've never seen it before. If a huge number of records are being deleted I could imagine it happening.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify the unit. We set 120 min for the ttl of the cache (cacheTtl = new Duration(TimeUnit.MINUTES, cacheTtl);) So nothing gets deleted for 2 hours, even if we don't do any other operations, a simple get takes 4-5x more time than with ttl disabled.

Comment: I think you'll need to share more of your configuration and how you're measuring access times. I just ran a small test and the difference is negligible (which is what I'd expect).

Comment: I attached a screenshot with the comparison of the 2 cases: I ran the same process (running for approx 10 min) with the same data, similar conditions, etc. When ttl was enabled the get took 55.5% (353 s) & the deserialize 37.7% (240s), with disabled ttl: the get took 16.2% (98s) & the deserialize 73.9% (447s). I have a replicated cache, but in this particular case I had only 1 node.

Comment: Instrumentation can add a high overhead to the measured time and also shift the overall time highly depending on the number of methods called.
How much is the difference when you use sampling for measurement instead?
How much is the difference when you measure the wall clock time without any profiler attached?

Comment: @Simulant - indeed instrumentation adds a high overhead, the whole process is much slower than without the profiler, but I see the same ratio when the  profiler is not attached or is attached in sampling mode. Actually I noticed that something is wrong because the whole process takes much more time than it should, and only after that I attached the profiler to see where the problem is.

Comment: I suggest you open a ticket. Looking at the profile, it makes sense that it would be slower. Since you're using the Accessed policy, it has to update the TTL every time you read a record. I bet if you use the Created policy, the difference will be less. Even so, I can't explain why it would be 4-5x slower.